# Powershell start-process get failed

Tags: powershell

Greeting!

I am trying to install an application using PowerShell but I am getting issue with the start-process. If I try to run the command manually using PowerShell console it is getting installed without any issue. Below is the code which I am written so far.

```
Try
{
    $product = "IBM Datacap"
    $installed = Get-Application($product)
    
    "Check IBM Datacap 9.1.9 is already installed."
    $mod = "Server,Web"
$spath = "D:"
    
        
    if (-not ($installed))
    {
     "Found application IBM Datacap 9.1.9 is not installed. Preparing to install the application. Please wait..."
    Push-Location "$toolsDir\IBM_Datacap_9.1.9"
    $binary = "$toolsDir\IBM_Datacap_9.1.9\Setup.exe"
    $list = "'/S /V""/passive INSTALLDIR=""$spath\Datacap\"" /log ""$log"" ADDDEFAULT=LAP,Shared,$mod""'"
    $arguments = $list.replace("'","")
    [int]$result = (Start-Process "$binary" -Argumentlist $arguments -Wait -NoNewWindow -Passthru).ExitCode
    
    
    if ($result -eq '0' -or $result -eq '3010' -or $result -eq '1641')
    {   
     "IBM Datacap 9.1.9 installed sucessfully $($result)."
    Push-Location $toolsDir
    } Else {
    Throw ("IBM Datacap 9.1.9 installation failed with ERROR: $($result).")
    }
    } Else {
     "Found application IBM Datacap 9.1.9 is already installed. Skipping the installation and exiting the process." 
    Exit 0
    
    }   
} catch {   
     "$($_.Exception.Message). Refer log $logfile for more information."
    Exit $lastexitcode = $result
}
```

I tried preparing batch file and execute it using PowerShell still but still the same error. I tried very hard using multiple ways but no luck. Please help me to solve this error.[image]

Command is working smoothly on PowerShell console if use below syntax.

.\setup.exe /S /V"/passive INSTALLDIR="D:\Datacap" /log "C:\Build\Logs\IBMDATACAP\2023-06-27-024429\ibm_datacap919.log" ADDDEFAULT=LAP,Shared,Server"

Comment: Powershell does not automatically run with ADMIN.  Error may be due to not having permission.  Start PS by righ click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Then try your script.

Comment: Sample code:
`Start-Process -FilePath C:\temp\SQLServer2014SP3-KB4022619-x64-ENU.exe -ArgumentList '/quiet /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /Action=Patch /AllInstances' -Wait -Verb RunAs`

Comment: You have to use `-Verb RunAs` param to execute with admin privileges

Comment: what's `Get-Application`? Anyway don't call it with parentheses like that, it's usually a bad idea and may produce unexpected results. The parentheses in `[int]$result = (Start-Process...)` is also unnecessary

Comment: @jdweng I am running the PowerShell as admin only.

Comment: @MikeSh I have followed the sample code as well but still the same error while running from script

Comment: @phuclv I have tried running without parentheses getting error as Process has exited, so the requested information is not available..  ```Push-Location "$toolsDir\IBM_Datacap_9.1.9"
 $binary = "$toolsDir\IBM_Datacap_9.1.9\Setup.exe"
 $list = "'/S /V""/passive INSTALLDIR=""$($spath)\Datacap\"" /log ""$log"" ADDDEFAULT=LAP,Shared,$mod""'"
 $arguments = $list.replace("'","")
 $arguments
 [int]$result = Start-Process "$binary" -Argumentlist $arguments -Wait -NoNewWindow -Passthru```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I found a mistake and it is syntax error INSTALLDIR=""$($spath)\Datacap"" but this one is working when I execute manually. I changed to INSTALLDIR=""$($spath)\Datacap"" and it is working fine.